# How to Insert Data in Database through DataGridView in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am making a windows form application in c# , in which  there is a  grid view control which is bind to SQL server database. All want, to let user press CTRL + N and a new row appears as the first row of grid view and on entering data in that row, data should be inserted into database by pressing enter and with all validation checks. For this I am using text boxes, but don't know how to do it with grid view.

```
 private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = DataConnection.GetConnection().CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into CustomerMaster(CustId,Name,City,State,Pin,ContactInfo) values(@custid,@name,@city,@state,@pin,@contactinfo)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@custid", txtcustid.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", txtname.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@city", txtcity.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@state", txtstate.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pin", txtpin.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@contactinfo", txtcontactinfo.Text));

            bool ans = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
            if (ans)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Insertion Happens Successfully");

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Insertion doesnot Happens");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Comment: What you tried ? Post your code

Comment: for inserting data,I use a tab control in which in one tab there is grid view to show data and in another tab there are labels and their associated textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple questions. I will answer the "how to add empty row" one.

For that After you populate your dataset and before you bind it to the Grid you should add an empty row to the top of this dataset.

```
' insert a blank row at the top
  Dim dr As DataRow = MyGrid.Tables(0).NewRow()
  dr("MyFiled") = "0"
  MyGrid.Tables(0).Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0)
```

There are many articles on internet showing how to save data. If you have problem with those please write your specific code here.